# I need to get value for scale() then taking diff() for the scaled value and getting back the original scaled values.I dont know why its not comming

Tags: r, time-series

I need something like

```
x <- id$time

[1] 20  4  5 16 30 15 45  7  8 12

 scal = scale(id$time)
             [,1]
 [1,]  0.29636894
 [2,] -0.95150029
 [3,] -0.87350846
 [4,] -0.01559837
 [5,]  1.07628721
 [6,] -0.09359019
 [7,]  2.24616461
 [8,] -0.71752481
 [9,] -0.63953298
[10,] -0.32756567
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 16.2
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 12.82186


diff(scal)

            [,1]    
 [1,] -1.24786923    
 [2,]  0.07799183    
 [3,]  0.85791010    
 [4,]  1.09188558    
 [5,] -1.16987740    
 [6,]  2.33975481    
 [7,] -2.96368942    
 [8,]  0.07799183    
 [9,]  0.31196731
```

Below shown is the output which I'm expecting but I'm not getting.I don't know its a stupid question o something. If anyone know how to get original scaled values after diff will be very helpful

```
cum = cumsum(diff(scal))

            [,1]    
 [1,]  0.29636894    
 [2,] -0.95150029    
 [3,] -0.87350846    
 [4,] -0.01559837    
 [5,]  1.07628721    
 [6,] -0.09359019    
 [7,]  2.24616461    
 [8,] -0.71752481    
 [9,] -0.63953298    
[10,] -0.32756567

original_data <- unscale(cum,scaled)

original_data

[1] 20  4  5 16 30 15 45  7  8 12
```

Comment: Two problems: taking `diff` removes the location of the vector, so you need to add back `x[1]` to all elements of `cum`.  Also, there is no function `unscale` - you have to use the two `attr` values to recreate the original values from the scales ones.

Comment: can u say how to use the `attr` values to get original values.And `unscale` is a function under DMwR library.

Comment: OK - I'm not familiar with that library.  The function would somehow need to know what the scaling parameters are, so you need to pass it `scal` as the second argument (not `scaled`).  To unscale manually, the relationship is `original_value = scaled:center + scaled:scale * scaled_value`, so if you apply this to `x[1]+cum` you should get the original back.

Comment: Got it...... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(DMwR)

x <- id$time

[1] 20  4  5 16 30 15 45  7  8 12

new = scale(x)

diff(new)
cumsum(diff(new))
new[1]
> 0.2963689

v = c(0.29636894, 0.29636894 + cumsum(diff(new)))

original_data <- unscale(v,new)
```